# How to make roles changes affect users without logoff?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to make changes in users roles affect users without the need to logoff?

It is not complicated to implement a mechanism to logoff a specific user after changes on it´s permissions but I would like to have changes working while user is still on.

Comment: Just want to be clear, are you using Forms or Windows authentication? And what are you using to manage your roles?

Comment: I am using Forms Autentication and Asp Net Membership to control users, roles and access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it by using [setinterval](/questions/tagged/setinterval) function in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Set the timer to update the Session value for the current user's role in Action Method. Below code is going to database to fetch the updated value after 2 minutes. You can use this function in the Layout.

```
setInterval("UpdateRoles();", 120000);
```

Sample Ajax call to the Action Method to update role present in Session value.

```
function UpdateRoles() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Your Url',
        data: JSON.stringify("Parameter list"),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        debugger;
    }).fail(function (data) {
        debugger;
    }).always(function(data) { 
        alert("complete"); 
    });
}
```